# Append in SQL When field is NULL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

i'm trying to make one append when my field is NULL (NULLABLE field), but it didn't work...

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET YourColumn = YourColumn + 'Appended Data'
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
UPDATE YourTable
    SET YourColumn = COALESCE(YourColumn, '') + 'Appended Data';
```